# GRUB prefix and root point to a nonexistent path: is this machine dead?

Tags: boot, grub, boot-loader

In an attempt to revamp an old (2013) laptop which had Windows and Ubuntu dually installed, I kept running into the grub rescue shell. From the get go, this was worrying to me.

The output of `ls`:

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)
```

None of them are valid filesystems (I get `unknown filesystem` when I want to ls the contents) which worried me even more. Then my penny dropped and I typed `set`. Its output:

```
cmdpath=(hd0)
prefix=(hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub
root=hd0,msdos5
```

*What on earth am I to do?* Can I create a partition inside of grub rescue?

Note that I can't boot from anything except my hard drive and network. I'm starting to think that it might be easier to try and set a Linux PXE up, but I have no clue on how to do that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A 2013's laptop should be able to boot from USB. I recommend trying https://sourceforge.net/projects/supergrub2/ before exploring the PXE option. Alternatively, you may physically extract the hard-drive from the device to examine the drive's content using another computer. Unless the hard-drive is critically damaged, I suspect all you need is running `grub-install` with `--(r/b)oot-directory` pointing to the correct partition.

Comment: @Hermann It *should* be able to boot from USB, but it can't. I only have two boot options (Hard Disk and Network) and the Hard Disk option obviously gives me the grub rescue shell.

Comment: Systems of that era sometimes list the USB as a sub-entry of "Hard Disk". If that is not the case, and based on my personal experience, extracting the drive will be the faster option.

Comment: @Hermann Alright, thanks for the tips!

Comment: @Hermann Please post answers as answers, not comments.